# Simple_form_for on Rails - how to show error validations after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I'm trying to only show errors in my form when the user clicks the submit button but currently, it is displaying all errors before the user clicks the submit button. How do I only show errors when the user submits the form?

I'm using simple-form in Rails

Here is my simple-form:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-5 col-md-offset-4 mx-auto">
  <%= simple_form_for @customer, url: customers_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email, input_html: { autocomplete: 'email' } %>
  <%= f.input :budget, collection: ["€200,000 - €299,999", "€300,000 - €399,999", "€400,000 - €499,999", "€500,000 - €649,999", "€650,000 - €799,999", "€800,000 - €1,000,000", "€1,000,000 +"] %>
  <%= f.input :comments, :as => :text, :input_html => { 'rows' => 10, 'cols' => 10 } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "btn-primary trigger mt-1" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here are my customer validations in my customer model:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, uniqueness: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
  validates :budget, presence: true
  validates :comments, presence: true
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can change simple_form_for (line 2) like this below

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer, html: { novalidate: true }, url: customers_path, method: :post do |f| %>
```

#### explanation:

by adding **, html: { novalidate: true }** This option adds a new novalidate property to the form, instructing it to skip all HTML 5 validation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this

I tried this but it didn't change anything - the errors still show. Also, I was trying to get it so that the errors only show after I click the submit button. Currently, it shows beforehand

Any idea how to stop that from happening?